# sale price, interest per annum and percentage increase or decrease

Tags: statistics

Mary bought a computer on hire purchase. If the cash price on the computer was $3 million and 25% was down payment if bought on hire purchase. If the balance was paid in 12 monthly installment at 12% interest per annum.

Find the percentage increase or decrease if computer was bought on cash price.

Comment: There is a possible ambiguity here.  There are different types of interest rates and you haven't told us which.  When you say 12% per annum, have you learned that will translate to 1% per month (i.e., just divide by 12)?  This first type would be called a nominal interest rate.  Or, have you needed to do a calculation like $1.12^{1/12}-1$ to get the interest rate?  This calculation is necessary if 12% is an effective annual interest rate.

Answer (score 1):

If purchased on hire price : Then,
The cash price= 3 million dollar 
Down payment: 0.75 million dollar
The interest calculated = (2.25*12/100) = $0.6075 million 
So, percentage decrease if computer was bought on cash price = (0.6075*100)/3 = 20.25%

Thanks